# How do you import a cmake project from the local filesystem, into cmake?

Tags: cmake

I come from a monorepo background, and I'm trying to break that habit.  My current goal is to split off a simple util library, and use it from two different hobby projects, without sacrificing the ability to make changes to it in tandem with the hobby project.

This is what I have so far.

```
Source/
  util/
    log.h
    log.cc
    macro.h
    CMakeLists.txt
  proj1/
    main.cc
    CMakeLists.txt
```

util/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.4)

project(util)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_library(util INTERFACE log.cc)
  target_include_directories(util INTERFACE .)
```

proj1/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.4)

project(proj1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

# I'm confident the error is in this block; I don't know how to tell
# ExternalProject_Add "import a standard cmake project from this folder".
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(util_utility
  SOURCE_DIR "/home/my_user/Source/util/"
  BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/util_bin"
  INSTALL_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/util_install"
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
  # I copied this from some mailinglist, in the hopes that it meant
  # "make a normal cmake"
  CMAKE_GENERATOR ${gen})
add_library(util STATIC IMPORTED)
  # I don't understand what this is, but if I don't pass it _something_,
  # then I get several warnings on the command line.
  set_property(TARGET util PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/util_install")
  add_dependencies(util util_utility)

add_executable(main main.cc)
   target_link_libraries(main util)
```

When I run `cd _build; cmake .. && make VERBOSE=1` in util/, it works.

When I run the same command in proj1/, I get

```
/usr/bin/c++  -I/home/my_user/Source/proj1/_build -std=gnu++2a -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cc.o -c /home/my_user/Source/proj1/main.cc
...
/home/my_user/Source/proj1/main.cc:3:10: fatal error: log.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include "log.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Now, clearly, the immediate problem is that my util library isn't in the includes being passed to `/usr/bin/c++`.  What am I missing?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why bother with the external project/imported lib and not simply do `add_subdirectory(/home/my_user/Source/util "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/util_build_dir")` in `proj1/CMakeLists.txt` and build both `util` and `main` via the same make file?

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, that worked, after some additional tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to fabian, here's what worked:

util/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.4)

project(util)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_library(util log.cc)
  target_include_directories(util INTERFACE .)
```

proj1/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.4)

project(proj1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_subdirectory("/home/my_user/Source/util"
                 "util_build") # util

add_executable(main main.cc)
  target_link_libraries(main util)
  add_dependencies(main util)
```